# How to use 128 bit integers in Cython

Tags: c, gcc, cython, long-integer, int128

On my 64 bit computer the `long long` type has 64 bits.

```
print(sizeof(long long))
# prints 8
```

I need to use 128 bit integers and luckily [GCC supports these](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html). How can I use these within Cython?

The following doesn't work. Compiling `foo.pyx` containing just

```
cdef __int128_t x = 0
```

yields

```
$ cython foo.pyx 

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

cdef __int128_t x = 0
    ^
------------------------------------------------------------

foo.pyx:2:5: '__int128_t' is not a type identifier
```

Comment: @BrettHale I can't just type `cdef __int128_t x = 0`. It doesn't compile.

Comment: What exactly is `cdef` in this context?

Comment: Apparently it isn't clear that this question is about cython, even though it says in the title.

Comment: What doesn't compile, the cython source or the generated C source?

Comment: @iharob The cython source: `'__int128' is not a type identifier`

Comment: @Chiel92 I don't think it's possible, since there is no native 128 integer in python.

Comment: @iharob With the same reasoning one wouldn't have a 64 bit int either, since python doesn't have those either. In python ints are of arbitrary size.

Comment: @Chiel92 there are no 64 bit integers in python, it's just that on 64 bit machine `sizeof(long int) = 8`, and python integers are `long int`'s, well python 2 supports `long int`, python 3 requires that integers be `long int`'s.

Comment: @iharob the question is not about python, but cython. You can use various C structures/types in cython WITHOUT exposing/using them in python.

Comment: @Chiel92, please post the compilation log, and a minimal example as well, with compilation flags, etc..

Comment: @GiulioGhirardo question updated

Answer (score 11, accepted):

EDIT: this is NOT a workaround anymore, this is the right way to do it. Refer also to @IanH's answer.

Now, the problem you have is that `cython` does not recognize your type, while `gcc` does. So we can try to trick `cython`.

File `helloworld.pyx`:

```
cdef extern from "header_int128.h":
    # this is WRONG, as this would be a int64. it is here
    # just to let cython pass the first step, which is generating
    # the .c file.
    ctypedef unsigned long long int128

print "hello world"

cpdef int foo():
    cdef int128 foo = 4
    return 32
```

File `header_int128.h`:

```
typedef __int128_t int128;
```

File `setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules = cythonize("helloworld.pyx"))
```

Now, on my machine, when I run `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`, the first step passes, and the file `helloworld.c` is generated, and then the `gcc` compilation passes as well.

Now if you open the file `helloworld.c`, you can check that your variable `foo` is actually declared as an `int128`.

Be very careful with using this workaround. In particular, it can happen that cython will not require a cast in the C code if you assign an `int128` to a `int64` for example, because at that step of the process it actually does not distinguish between them.

Comment: While it compiles indeed, I can't seem to store a number of more than 64 bits in it. The code `cdef int128 bar = 1 << 64 \n print(bar)` prints `0`. On the other hand, `sizeof(int128)` says `16`, like we want.

Comment: I did also try the simple cast in a C++ only code, and it casted an `int128` larger than an `int64` to `0`. I guess this is then not a limitation of `cython`, but something inherently wrong with `__int128_t`, at least on my machine.

Comment: The type `__int128` works fine for me in C (other than that many functions can't handle them). Doesn't the line `ctypedef unsigned long long int128` mean that you set `int128` to be an alias for `unsigned long long`?

Comment: Yes, but that is just a placeholder, to let the cython processo finish successfully. When you compile the code, the compiler includesse the real header and does noto read that ctypedef.

Comment: I posted an answer containing an example of your solution. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @gg349 could you post an example of a C code where converting from __int128 to double fails on x86_64? It seems to work fine to me...

Comment: @Marc, I have updated my compiler to gcc-4.9 and I can't reproduce the wrong casting anymore, and I updated the answer. It works with something like `__int128_t foo = 1152921504606846976;`, `foo = foo*foo;`, and then with `std::cout<<(double)foo;`. I have noticed that if I initialize `foo` to a large number (say `2**120`), I get a compilation warning, but then gcc writes `0` instead of that constant! I am not sure if I got it wrong in the first instance because of this, or because of the older version of `gcc` I was using.

Answer (score 5):

I'll throw my two cents in here.

First, the solution proposed in the other answers saying to use an external typedef is not just a workaround, that is the way the Cython docs say things like this should be done.
See [the relevant section](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#referencing-c-header-files).
Quote: "If the header file uses typedef names such as `word` to refer to platform-dependent flavours of numeric types, you will need a corresponding ctypedef statement, but you don’t need to match the type exactly, just use something of the right general kind (int, float, etc). For example `ctypedef int word` will work okay whatever the actual size of a `word` is (provided the header file defines it correctly). Conversion to and from Python types, if any, will also be used for this new type."

Also, it isn't necessary to actually create a header file with a typedef for a type you've already included somewhere else along the way.
Just do this

```
cdef extern from *:
    ctypedef int int128 "__int128_t"
```

Or, if you feel like keeping the name the same in Cython as it is in C,

```
cdef extern from *:
    ctypedef int __int128_t
```

Here's a test to demonstrate that this is working.
If the 128 bit arithmetic is working, `a > 1`, and a is representable as a 64 bit integer, the first function will print the same number back again.
If it is not, integer overflow should cause it to print 0.
The second function shows what happens if 64 bit arithmetic is used.

Cython file

```
# cython: cdivision = True

cdef extern from *:
    ctypedef int int128 "__int128_t"

def myfunc(long long a):
    cdef int128 i = a
    # set c to be the largest positive integer possible for a signed 64 bit integer
    cdef long long c = 0x7fffffffffffffff
    i *= c
    cdef long long b = i / c
    print b

def myfunc_bad(long long a):
    cdef long long i = a
    # set c to be the largest positive integer possible for a signed 64 bit integer
    cdef long long c = 0x7fffffffffffffff
    i *= c
    cdef long long b = i / c
    print b
```

In Python, after both functions have been imported, `myfunc(12321)` prints the correct value while `myfunc_bad(12321)` prints 0.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example for using the hack proposed by @Giulio Ghirardo.

The file `cbitset.px` contains:

```
typedef unsigned __int128 bitset;
```

The file `bitset.pyx` contains:

```
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc
from libc.stdio cimport printf

cdef extern from "cbitset.h":
    ctypedef unsigned long long bitset

cdef char* bitset_tostring(bitset n):
    cdef char* bitstring = <char*>malloc(8 * sizeof(bitset) * sizeof(char) + 1)
    cdef int i = 0
    while n:
        if (n & <bitset>1):
            bitstring[i] = '1'
        else:
            bitstring[i] = '0'

        n >>= <bitset>1
        i += 1
    bitstring[i] = '\0'
    return bitstring

cdef void print_bitset(bitset n):
    printf("%s\n", bitset_tostring(n))
```

The file `main.pyx` contains:

```
from bitset cimport print_bitset

cdef extern from "cbitset.h":
    ctypedef unsigned long long bitset

# x contains a number consisting of more than 64 1's
cdef bitset x = (<bitset>1 << 70) - 1

print_bitset(x)
# 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

The file `setup.py` contains:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    name="My app that used 128 bit ints",
    ext_modules=cythonize('main.pyx')
)
```

Compile this using the command

```
python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

and run using the command

```
python3 -c 'import main'
```