# Wrong calculation when using Cython

Tags: python, cython

I implemented [Lucas-Lehmer primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test) to check Mersenne prime in python. Then I use Cython to speed up the calculation.

- **Original Python code:**

```
def lucas_lehmer(p):    
    if p == 2:
        return True

    s = 4
    M = (1 << p) - 1

    for i in range(p-2):    
        s = ((s * s) - 2) % M
        print("Processed: {}%".format(100*i//(p-2)))

    if s == 0:
        return True

    else:
        return False
```

- **Cython code:**

```
cpdef lucas_lehmer(int p):    
    if p == 2:
        return True

    cdef unsigned long long int M
    M = (1 << p) - 1

    cdef unsigned long long int s
    s = 4

    cdef int i

    for i in range(p-2):    
        s = ((s * s) - 2) % M
        print("Processed: {}%".format(100*i//(p-2)))

    if s == 0:
        return True

    else:
        return False
```

Running the original Python code, it works correctly. But for Cython, it's only correct with `p = 31` and lower, testing with `p = 61` and bigger (all tested p values are values that `2^p-1` is prime), it returns False (not a prime number), except for `p = 86243`.

For some p like 97, even though `2^97-1` is not a prime number, the program actually return True (is a prime number), which is a contradiction.

Why does this happen? Without using cdef for variable `M` and `s`, the calculation will be correct, but the performance won't get any improved.

Comment: Why is there a `M` parameter in the Python code if it's overwritten immediately after?

Comment: Surely that's just some overflow? Are you asking where exactly it happens?

Comment: `M = (1 << p) - 1` How do you think `M` is being stored?  Perhaps you should try to define a type that Cython and C understands.  There are examples on StackOverflow and elsewhere that show how to define 128-bit integers for Cython.

Comment: @rickhg12hs I've tried from the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27582001/how-to-use-128-bit-integers-in-cython.  When I compile, I get the error: `int128: undeclared identifier`

Comment: 128bit integer is only a gcc extension (do you use gcc?), and it would not help here because the problem happens when (1<<32) is executed.

Comment: However, for p>64 (or p>128) you will need to use libraries which support arbitrary size integer (or use Python-integer, which isn't a bad choice).

Comment: @ead I don't use gcc

Comment: @ead Can I use GMP in cython?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/48447427/5769463

Answer (score 0):

Running a few tests on your code I found that M was always equal to 1
so I defined p as a cdef and got the required result.

Not sure exactly what the issue is but it's something to do with that bit operation on p. p needs to be of the same type as M for it to make sense and if one is cdef and one is python int somehow it doesn't work?

```
cpdef lucas_lehmer(int py):    
    cdef p
    p = py
    if p == 2:
        return True

    cdef M
    M = (1 << p) - 1

    cdef s
    s = 4

    cdef int i

    for i in range(p-2):    
        s = ((s * s) - 2) % M
        print("Processed: {}%".format(100*i//(p-2)))

    if s == 0:
        return True

    else:
        return False
```

Comment: This code works fine for me but I don't see any performance improvement. It didn't faster than python interpreter.